# Does keepalived work with team driver?

Tags: rhel7, keepalived

I am trying to configure keepalived on RHEL's team driver.

http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2014/06/23/team-driver/

My keepalived instance is recognizing *MASTER* and *BACKUP* but virtual ip is not created on team interface.

Below is keepalived configuration.

```
global_defs {
   notification_email {
     root@localhost.localdomain
   }

   notification_email_from root@localhost.localdomain
}

vrrp_script check_service {
  script /usr/local/src/check_service.sh
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
}

vrrp_instance SERVICE_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface team0
    virtual_router_id 50
    priority 101
    advert_int 1
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.213.140.xx dev team0
    }
    track_script {
      check_service
    }
}
```

Does anyone know whether team driver support virtual ip with keepalived?